# Ridiculous problem with CDATA

Tags: metabox

I'm using this great metabox plugin:
https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2

I created a repeatable field (with only one textarea that you can duplicate)

It's working great. Now, I want to export some pages that includes these textareas. The export goes well, I enter the XML and I can see all the data: (check `iswp_sections_group`)

```
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>iswp_sections_group</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:7:"content";s:56:"[shortcode var='value']
testing shortcode
[/shortcode]";}i:1;a:1:{s:7:"content";s:56:"[shortcode var='value']
testing shortcode
[/shortcode]";}}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
```

Full Gist:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba15d2b89de6d492e8a6

But I can't import the data properly. the `<wp:meta_value>` escapes for some reason.
I've been looking for an answer for the last 2 days.

Please anyone?

Comment: Please contact the plugin author. Third party plugins are off topic

Comment: CDATA stuff is very normal in XML and shouldn't cause any issues. What exactly happens on import?

Comment: Empty row on the field in the database.. this can be fixed by remove all newlines in the textareas, but it's a mess and not easy to edit..